# Why aren't there any $S_8$ or $S_{12}$ point groups in crystallography?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, symmetric-groups, symmetry, crystallography

Asked this question in Physics Stack Exchange, but may be readers of Maths Stack Exchange can answer it too.

When considering improper rotations (roto-reflections), we can derive that if $n$ is odd, then $C_n$ and $\sigma_h$ (reflection plane normal to $C_n$ axis) must exist. Similarly, we can also derive that if $n$ is even, then $C_n/2$ and $\sigma_h$ (reflection plane must exist).

Further, when considering crystallographic point groups, we can easily derive that there are no rotation operations other than $1$-, $2$-, $3$-, $4$- and $6$- fold axes. Now, considering the above-mentioned fact that for improper rotations and for $n$ = even, $C_n/2$ must exist, we can say that $n/2 = 4 $ and $6$ must be allowed and therefore, improper rotations of the kind $S_8$ and $S_{12}$ must be allowed as well. However, that is not the case. Is there any algebraic/geometrical proof for this? I tried looking everywhere including textbooks and various online pages, but no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: According to something I found, $S_8$ and $S_{12}$ symmetries don't work in crystals because the crystal requires $2cos(\tau/d)$ to be an integer--I'm not entirely certain why, though! That expression is an integer for $d=2,3,4,6$, but no other values of $d$.

Comment: I came across something similar before posting here too! The argument 2cos(2pi/8) needs to be an integer is something that helps derive that only 1-, 2-, 3-, 4- and 6-fold axes are found for *proper* rotations, i.e., only rotations without any reflections. However, not sure how that is applicable for improper rotations, i.e., roto-reflections too, since for roto-reflections of order n, where n is even, only proper rotations of the order n/2 are mandatory. So, for 8-fold improper rotations, existence of 4-fold proper rotation (C4, which is allowed) should suffice. But, still S8 is not allowed.

Comment: [Maybe these symmetries are allowed.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal)